# Cannot upload a file to a specific folder using Google API v2 PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have searched alot and tried many possible solutions, but none of them worked. I just downloaded Google api library from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client, I set my client id and secret key, and I can upload the example.txt to my google drive,

I added:

```
if ($parentId != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($parentId);
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    }
```

I also tried adding the property 'parents' as array:

```
$service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
         'mimeType' => $mime_type
         'parents' =>array('0B_42pI7gZxDjRWVfNGpxNm1pc0E')
    ));
```

It didnt work, below is the current code:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $parentId = '0B_42pI7gZxDjRWVfNGpxNm1pc0E'; //I added this
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
     // Set the parent folder (THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED but doesn't work)
    if ($parentId != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($parentId);
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    }

    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);

        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type,

            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
}
```

now I would like to upload to a specific folder, I have the folder_id already.

Comment: It seems that your script is for Drive API v2. But it seems that the request body is for Drive API v3. Which version do you want to use v2 or v3?

Comment: Wouldn't recommend to write any new code against a deprecated API... just use v3.

Comment: it's API v2, as I didn't find API v3 library

Comment: Did you try to use exactly the code from the official documentation? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert ($file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();...) I would also recommend you to test the upload with "Try this API"  to make sure that your Parent ID etc. is correct. As for v3, there is a small sample for uploading files here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: thanks, I decided to use v3 instead